# responsive grid is broken by span element with empty value

Tags: html, css, angularjs, stylus, jeet-grid

I get the JSON from the site.  Some of the fields of this JSON is empty ("").  I have a HTML(Jade) code like this:

```
 div(ng-repeat="item in itemsToDisplay", class="item tableLine")
    span(class="tableItemid")
        a(href="#/itemDetail/{{ item.Itemid }}") {{ item.Itemid }}
    span(class="tableItemdescription")
        {{ item.Itemdescription }}
    span(class="tableDate")
        {{ item.CreationDate }}
    span(class="tableCountry")
        {{ item.Address }}
```

And css (slylus) like this:

```
span.tableItemid
   col(1/15)
span.tableItemdescription
   col(3/15)
span.tableDate
   col(2/15)
```

If the fields is empty the span is empty. And I have offset in the responsive grid.  What is the best way to avoid it?

Comment: You  could use Javascript to detect if an object is empty or not (`if ($('#element').is(':empty')){//do something}`). If the object is empty you could apply a different style. Would that help?

Comment: Now I'm just add a transparent image (1px), but I'm searching for more jeet specific solutions